# Link of react-router-dom updates the URL without rendering the component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using the react-router-dom Link component to manage my navigation but it doesn't work.
The Link changes the URL but doesn't render the component.
Here is a simple app describing my problem. I'm trying to use My App header as go home link:

```
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/events">
        <h1>My Application</h1>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};
const ConnectedNavigation = connect((state) => state)(Navigation);

export default ConnectedNavigation;
```

App.jsx code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from '../store/index';
import ConnectedDashboard from './Dashboard';
import ConnectedEventDetails from './EventDetails';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { history } from '../store/history';
import ConnectedNavigation from './Navigation';

export const Main = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div>
        <ConnectedNavigation />
        <Route exact path="/events" render={() => <ConnectedDashboard />} />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/event/:id"
          //match prop is necessary in order to determine which event
          //we are looking for
          render={({ match }) => <ConnectedEventDetails match={match} />}
        />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  </Router>
);
```

As you can see i added exact on my Routes to avoid any confusions

Comment: You need to wrap your Route components by Switch component

Comment: Tried that but didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem comes from this line:

```
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

The correct import is :

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```